# missing comma error while inserting using SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting this error while inserting values in a table. I have more than 500 rows to insert. More than 100 rows have been inserted using same method but it gets an error in this line.

```
INSERT INTO CHICAGO_CRIME_DATA (ID, CASE_NUMBER, DT, BLOCK, IUCR, PRIMARY_TYPE, DESCRIPTION, LOCATION_DESCRIPTION, ARREST, DOMESTIC, BEAT, DISTRICT, WARD, COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER, FBICODE, X_COORDINATE, Y_COORDINATE, YEAR, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, LOCATION) 
VALUES (7646435.0, 'HS451246', '8/7/2010', '023XX W ROSCOE ST', 460.0, 'BATTERY', 'SIMPLE', 'SIDEWALK', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 1913.0, 19.0, 32.0, 5.0, 08B, 1160352.0, 1922529.0, 2010.0, 41.94312358, -87.68603108, '(41.943123577, -87.686031082)')
```

Comment: what's datatype of "location"?

Comment: `08B` should be `'08B'`. Assuming `FBICODE` is a string column; if not then your data is bad. That is causing that error anyway. (Also `'8/7/2010'` appears to be going into a date column so you should really use `to_date()` or a date literal. not a string literal.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is raised because of this value "08B" , for FBICODE column,

seems like it should be wrapped in singlqquote

Comment: Thanks. But previous 100 rows were inserted without any error. I have used import table function from sql developer and trying to insert data from a csv file.

Comment: @MohammadLitonHossain because last 100 rows didn't have bad data , but this row has

Comment: Thanks everyone. There are some bad data in my data set.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `08B` you need to use `'08B'`

Corrected Query:

```
INSERT INTO CHICAGO_CRIME_DATA (ID, CASE_NUMBER, DT, BLOCK, IUCR, PRIMARY_TYPE, DESCRIPTION, LOCATION_DESCRIPTION, ARREST, DOMESTIC, BEAT, DISTRICT, WARD, COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER, FBICODE, X_COORDINATE, Y_COORDINATE, YEAR, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, LOCATION) 
VALUES (7646435.0, 'HS451246', '8/7/2010', '023XX W ROSCOE ST', 460.0, 'BATTERY', 'SIMPLE', 'SIDEWALK', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 1913.0, 19.0, 32.0, 5.0, '08B', 1160352.0, 1922529.0, 2010.0, 41.94312358, -87.68603108, '(41.943123577, -87.686031082)')
```